# Cassandra Select Query Without Timeout

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a 3 node datastax cassandra(Community) cluster with huge data. I have few tables which contain 3-5 billion records in them. I want to delete data that is older than 90 days from those tables.

The problem is how do i run a select query which runs without timeout. I am currently running below query

NOW=$(date -d "-3 month" +"%Y-%m-%d")
select day_ts from table_name where minute_ts < '$NOW' LIMIT 100000 ALLOW FILTERING;

Even if i limit the select query result, it will still parse the whole 3-5 billion records and then filter the data.

Please suggest what can be a efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. "ALLOW FILTERING" queries don't scale. You should change the data model to satisfy your queries. If you inherited this model, you have to read the whole dataset and store again with a different model. there's no escapes...

Comment: Agreed with @xmas79, you we'll need to filter the holw dataser and transfer it to a different model; on the new model ensure that the TTL (Time to live) is set properly so you won't have this issue in the future

Comment: Here is my table structure.

Comment: CREATE TABLE table_name ( srcip inet, log_datemin timestamp,id uuid, PRIMARY KEY (srcip, log_datemin, id) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (log_datemin ASC, id ASC) AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND comment = '' AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';